# Viariable tags in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm using this command in C#:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in 
     htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='discussion r1']"))
```

The problem is that I need all node that contains `rX`:

```
 discussion r0
 discussion r1
 discussion r2
```

How can I select all `rX` nodes?
And how can I select only `r0` and `r1` in one foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HtmlNode.SelectNodes()` only support XPath 1.0 which doesn't have regex matching function. Using simple XPath `starts-with()` or `contains()` function should do the trick :

```
//using starts-with()
htmlDoc.DocumentNode
       .SelectNodes("//tr[starts-with(@class,'discussion r')]")
//or using contains()
htmlDoc.DocumentNode
       .SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@class,'discussion r')]")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works.

2 Precisation:
- Are there some performance's differences between "starts-with" and "contains"?
- How can I select only r1 and r2 nodes and not r3?

Comment: 1. I don't think there is noticeable performance difference between the two functions. 2. You can use XPath `or` operator, but if you meant to match with range like r1 to r11, but not r12 and above, I'd suggest to use HAP's LINQ API instead of using XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a regular expression (using the `matches` function) to match the `rX`,

- `//tr[matches(@class,'discussion r.')]` if there is only one character after the `r`
- `//tr[matches(@class,'discussion r.+')]` when there is at least one
- `//tr[matches(@class,'discussion r\d+')]` if it need to be followed by a number